# How do I download multiple videos from YouTube with Multiline TextBox?

Tags: c#, download, textbox

How do I download multiple videos from YouTube with Multiline TextBox?

Here is my code so far:

```
var split = txtURL.Text.Split(',');
for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++) {
    IEnumerable<VideoInfo> videolar = DownloadUrlResolver.GetDownloadUrls(split[i]);
    VideoInfo video = videolar.First(p => p.VideoType == VideoType.Mp4 &&
        p.Resolution == Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.Text));
    if (video.RequiresDecryption) {
        DownloadUrlResolver.DecryptDownloadUrl(video);
    }
    VideoDownloader downloader = new VideoDownloader(video,
        Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath + "\\ " + video.Title +
            GetSafeFileName(video.Title, '_') + video.VideoExtension));
    downloader.DownloadProgressChanged += Downloader_DownloadProgressChanged;
    Thread thread = new Thread(() => { downloader.Execute(); }) { IsBackground = true };
    thread.Start();
}
```

Comment: please help me out :(

Comment: There is no easy way to get youtube videos download link, Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Yes, I can get url with YouTube search, but I can not make bulk download

Comment: So what is the problem whit you code? Have you an error?

Comment: Multiple downloading. Not downloading one by one

Comment: I want to process for each row

Comment: You have `split ` array and for each item you create one thread to download a video(as i see). So why it is not a multiple downloading?

Comment: Yes, as you see.
"," I want i to download the previous URL, and download the next one.
How can I make a separate transaction for each row?

Comment: You mean all of this downloads(your code) is only for one row? and your textbox (txtUrl) has another rows?

Comment: multiline textbox, I want to do line-by-line processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**People who want to start this, Must add this nuget package:**

> Install-Package YoutubeExtractor

Here is the page: [YoutubeExtractor](https://github.com/flagbug/YoutubeExtractor)

Finally I download the URL Extractor and create the hole project.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    int currentLine = 0;
    ProgressBar progressBar1 = new ProgressBar();
    string[] lines;
    string resolution;

    private void btnIndir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        resolution = comboBox1.Text;  //360, 480, 720, 1080

        lines = txtURL.Text.Split(System.Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(DownloadNextLine);
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    public void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
        var split = lines[currentLine].Split(new char[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
        {
            IEnumerable<VideoInfo> videolar = DownloadUrlResolver.GetDownloadUrls(split[i]);
            VideoInfo video = videolar.First(p => p.VideoType == VideoType.Mp4 && p.Resolution == Convert.ToInt32(resolution));
            if (video.RequiresDecryption)
            {
                DownloadUrlResolver.DecryptDownloadUrl(video);
            }

            VideoDownloader downloader = new VideoDownloader(video, System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath + "\\ " + GetSafeFileName(video.Title) + '_' + video.VideoExtension));
            downloader.DownloadProgressChanged += downloader_DownloadProgressChanged;
            downloader.Execute();
        }
    }

    private string GetSafeFileName(string title)
    {
        title.Replace("/", "").Replace(",", "").Replace("\\", "").Replace("+", "");
        return title;
    }

    void downloader_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressEventArgs e)
    {
        SetPbValue((int)e.ProgressPercentage);
    }

    void SetPbValue(int percent)
    {
        if (progressBar2.InvokeRequired)
            progressBar2.Invoke(new Action<int>(SetPbValue), percent);
        else
            progressBar2.Value = percent;
    }

    public void DownloadNextLine(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        currentLine++;
        if (currentLine == lines.Length)
            return;
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

}
```

It tested and worked perfectly. And now i am happy to have this useful app. But if you error persists, I am definitely sure that one of the lines has an invalid video page url. And the comma ',' at the end is for the error explanation, not end of url. Because the items in `someText.Split(',')` will never have any comma.

Comment: My fool ...
I'm testing

Comment: Not work.. 
Download all the lines I want one by one.

Comment: Please see my last edit. The hard thing is i can not test codes to see the result, because i have not library **DownloadUrlSolver**. So I hope the code is true. If it is not make a comment with the problem. I will see that tomorrow and help. Good night.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm testing. Good night :)

Comment: line "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DDLDJofd0WE," error URL is not a valid youtube URL!
I get this error
Adding comma at the end.

Comment: Hey, your code not working :( please help me please :(

Comment: txtURL.txt 
rows : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o8MAptNxI7M,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qljcwGdfquQ,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V7W1otErAKM,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OBg8RtV72uQ,

Comment: I'm testing. Thank you so much.. Your c# professor :)

Comment: Waaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaowwww very nice worked !!! Very very very thank you bro..... :) :) :) :)

Comment: You welcome. Please check my answer as the true answer, maybe others can use our post.

Comment: Now i must thank you to made me to create this app!.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void btnIndir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                    progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
                    progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
                    var split = txtURL.Text.Split(',');
                    for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
                    {
                        IEnumerable<VideoInfo> videolar = DownloadUrlResolver.GetDownloadUrls(split[i]);
                        VideoInfo video = videolar.First(p => p.VideoType == VideoType.Mp4 && p.Resolution == Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.Text));
                        if (video.RequiresDecryption)
                        {
                            DownloadUrlResolver.DecryptDownloadUrl(video);
                        }
                        VideoDownloader downloader = new VideoDownloader(video, Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath + "\\ " + video.Title + GetSafeFileName(video.Title, '_') + video.VideoExtension));
                        downloader.DownloadProgressChanged += Downloader_DownloadProgressChanged;
                        Thread thread = new Thread(() => { downloader.Execute(); }) { IsBackground = true };
                        thread.Start();
            }
       }
```